# Too long to wake up screen

Tags: gnome, xorg, suspend, 20.04

I am using xorg + gnome3 + gdm3 on 20.04 (I think).

After entering the password on the login screen it takes too long (>1 min sometimes) to log in and show anything useful. When the screen goes blank and I am not logged out, it takes too long to bring colors back to the screen on the mouse/keyboard movement. However, I can move the mouse and see the cursor moving so it is not really the problem of being stuck due to high CPU usage.

More details:
I upgraded to 20.04 (beta) around January. I have been facing this problem intermittently for the past 2 months. Usually, when a laptop has been shut down recently (a few hours) I don't face this problem. My laptop goes to sleep after 5 min of inactivity and the screen goes blank(black) after 1 min of activity.

Edit: 
I am still using the beta with everything up-to-date. I am using dell latitude 6430u with integrated GPU (3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller)

I am not really sure where to look for a solution and happy to provide more details about the machine.

Update: (June 11, 2020)
This issue goes away after I starting using cinnamon DE

Comment: A vexing issue, to be sure. A) Still on the Beta or did you reinstall once the final release became available on the 23rd? B) Have you tried booting from a 20.04 LiveUSB to replicate the problem? C) If you can replicate it with a LiveUSB of 20.04, what happens with a LiveUSB of 18.04? D) What's the GPU and the video driver? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Thanks! I added as much information as I could. I am not sure if it would be possible to reproduce with live-USB as I said the problem is intermittent and only appears when using the machine for a long time. Sorry but I am not sure how to find the video driver.